# Importing Colored Graphics from Gnuplot to LaTeX

Tags: gnuplot

I have five data files each containing separate data. I have plotted them in Gnuplot and superimposed them; at this point I would like to emphasize that Gnuplot automatically chooses different color in printing. After this I set the output of Gnuplot to latex and have the desired data plotted by invoking the following with the load command in Gnuplot:

```
set terminal latex
set output "spectrum.tex"
set title "Spectrum"
set xlabel "Wavelength (nm)"
set ylabel "Power (cts)"
set ytics 200
set xr [550:750]
set yr [0:3200]
plot "ma3.txt" using 1:2 title"3 mA" with lines, \
"ma5.txt" using 1:2  title"5 mA" with lines, \
"ma10.txt" using 1:2 title"10 mA" with lines, \
"ma15.txt" using 1:2 title"15 mA" with lines, \
"ma20.txt" using 1:2 title"20 mA" with lines
```

However, when I moved the generated file to the directory where my main tex file reside and compiled to get the pdf output, I noticed that the graphic was entirely in black. I should note that I have included the packages graphicx and color in the preamble part of the source code. I am using Tex Live 2013 and TexMaker as a Latex editor. Thanks for your help in advance. The following is a minimal sample from my Latex document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{a4, color}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document} 
\input spectrum.tex

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `latex` terminal doesn't support coloured line styles. Try the `epslatex` terminal instead (or go with an all-LaTeX solution, like the PGFPlots package)

Comment: Okay, thanks for your suggestion I will give it a go.

Answer (score 2):

I saved the graphics as colored encapsulated postscript files. Afterwards I changed the extensions and

```
    set terminal postscript color enhanced
    set output *.eps 
...
    \includegraphics[scale=0.7,angle=-90]{pocu.eps}
...
```

That worked for me, I posted to inform you. Thank you all for your efforts.